# linux slurm - separate .out files for tasks run in paralell on 1 node

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, output, slurm

I am running jobs in parallel on linux using slurm by requesting a node and running one task per cpu.

However, the output as specified joins both streams into the single out file. I tried the %t flag on the epxectation it would separate the tasks, but it just logs everything in the output file with _0 appended (e.g. sample_output__XXX_XX_0.out).

Any advice on how to best generate a separate .out log per task would be much appreciated

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=recon_all_06172021_1829
#SBATCH --output=/path/recon_all_06172021_1829_%A_%a_%t.out
#SBATCH --error=/path/recon_all_06172021_1829_%A_%a.err
#SBATCH --ntasks=2
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=2
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --time=23:59:00

#! Always keep the following echo commands to monitor CPU, memory usage
echo "SLURM_MEM_PER_CPU: $SLURM_MEM_PER_CPU"
echo "SLURM_MEM_PER_NODE: $SLURM_MEM_PER_NODE"
echo "SLURM_JOB_NUM_NODES: $SLURM_JOB_NUM_NODES"
echo "SLURM_NNODES: $SLURM_NNODES"
echo "SLURM_NTASKS: $SLURM_NTASKS"
echo "SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK: $SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK"
echo "SLURM_JOB_CPUS_PER_NODE: $SLURM_JOB_CPUS_PER_NODE"

command 1 &
command 2
wait
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the standard output from the command itself, for example:

```
command 1 > file1 2>&1
command 2 > file2 2>&1
```

Not as neat as using the `sbatch` filename patterns, but it will separate the output from each command.

Comment: Could you explain the ```2>&1```?